# Convert IDW to DWG with AutoDesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a list of .idw files from an assembly .iam, there is a way to convert them in .dwg using AutoDesk Forge?

I don't see the conversion directly on the supported translation https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/

There is an alternative way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with Inventor API or iLogic development, you could build an Inventor plugin that generates the DWG (the online search does yield some [suggestions](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/inventor-ilogic-api-vba-forum/converting-idw-to-dwg/td-p/7258029)), deploy it to the [Forge Design Automation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3) service, and setup an automated pipeline that DWGs out of an Inventor design whenever needed.